# Admin system config fields are not displaying

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configuration

I am trying to add some config settings under Magento configuration and I had success with my module and a bit of XML code in system.xml but the problem is it is displaying only one field though I have defined four fields - it's just showing the last one, the `sort_order` for each input is defined as well.

Here is my system.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <mgconf translate="label">
            <label>Magegurus SMTP E-Mail</label>
            <sort_order>999</sort_order>
        </mgconf>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <mgsmtp translate="label" module="adminhtml">
            <label>Magegurus SMTP E-Mail</label>
            <tab>mgconf</tab>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label comment">
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <text_field translate="label comment">
                            <label>Host Name</label>
                            <comment>Your SMTP host name here.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </text_field>
                        <text_field translate="label comment">
                            <label>Port</label>
                            <comment>Your SMTP port here.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </text_field>

                        <text_field translate="label comment">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <comment>Your SMTP username here.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </text_field>

                        <text_field translate="label comment">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <comment>Your SMTP password here.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </text_field>
                    </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
        </mgsmtp>
    </sections>
</config>
```

The config is only showing last fields the **Password**.
Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because all the fields have the tag `text_field`. Name them differently and they should appear.
I mean something like:

```
                  <fields>
                    <text_field translate="label comment">
                        <label>Host Name</label>
                        <comment>Your SMTP host name here.</comment>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </text_field>
                    <text_field2 translate="label comment">
                        <label>Port</label>
                        <comment>Your SMTP port here.</comment>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </text_field2>
                    ....
                 </fields>
```

Comment: Thanks .. i thought `text_field` is for displaying text box.

Comment: no. In your case 'text_field' is the identifier of the field. You will later get the value like this: `Mage::getStoreConfig('mgsmtp/general/text_field')`. The type of the input is given by the tag `<frontend_type>`.

Comment: Hey..Thanks for your explanation. Any idea on how can i call some controller via ajax using system config.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Anyway, I don't think is related to this question. Post an other question with some additional details about your issue.